# Register database using a macro

Tags: database, vba, database-connection, porting, openoffice-calc

I am trying to register a new database in OpenOffice Calc, but I need to make it using a script (macro).

Is there any way to do it?
If not, can I work on unregistered database in my Calc macros?
If yes, how to do it?

I am porting my VBA macro to Calc and I have a problem connecting to dBase file. I got no working code at the moment, I can only provide my VBA script to show you what I need to do in Calc.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know too much about this but if you can create a DSN to your DBase file then it should be doable?  A DSN might be easier to work with when doing this.

Comment: I'd love to do so, but I have no idea on how to create Data Source from unregistered database file.

Comment: I might not fully understand your question... can you create a DSN o your dBase file by following this in Windows?


Start -> Administrative Tools -> Data Sources (ODBC) -> User-DSN-> Add

Comment: Oh, You mean doing it manually in Windows. No way, the spreadsheet will be moved around (used on different computers), it needs to dynamically get the database and use it.

Comment: Ok, I understand your question now - sorry I can't help with this in OpenOffice.  Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

This works

```
Private Sub Calculator_Click() 
'%SystemRoot%\system32\calc.exe 
On Error GoTo Err_Calculator_Click 
Dim stAppName As String 
stAppName = "C:\Windows\System32\calc.exe" 
Call Shell(stAppName, 1) 
Exit_Calculator_Click: 
Exit Sub 
Err_Calculator_Click: 
MsgBox Err.Description 
Resume Exit_Calculator_Click 

End Sub
```